# Resizing image in Django by overriding save method

Tags: django-models

I am specifically trying to resize an image during upload by max width while keeping the original ratio.  I am trying to write my own save method by piecing together others examples but I have a question.

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    #blablabla
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="...", blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.photo:
            basewidth = 300
            filename = self.get_source_filename()
                    image = Image.open(filename)
            wpercent = (basewidth/float(image.size[0]))
            hsize = int((float(image.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
            img = image.resize((basewidth,hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
            self.photo.save()
        super(Mymodel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

is it self.photo.save() ?  or img.save(), second to last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to save the photo, so you need to assign something to `self.photo` which is a field, so it won't have a save method. You need to reassign `self.photo` and then save the whole model.

I presume this is what you want:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Did we have to resize the image?
    # We pop it to remove from kwargs when we pass these along
    image_resized = kwargs.pop('image_resized',False)

    if self.photo and image_resized:
        basewidth = 300
        filename = self.get_source_filename()
                image = Image.open(filename)
        wpercent = (basewidth/float(image.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(image.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
        img = image.resize((basewidth,hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.photo = img
        # Save the updated photo, but inform when we do that we
        # have resized so we don't try and do it again.
        self.save(image_resized = True)

    super(Mymodel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble following this.  Where in this example would I specify the width?  do I just replace 'basewidth' with 320px (that's what I want).

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything.  Image does not get resized (I even checked media folder in case it saved a resized copy there and nothing).  Pictures just save in their original dimensions like they did previous to adding this code.  Oddly, there are no errors.  Not sure what's going on..

Comment: I'd double check the image resize code then, the django save portion should work as expected. It might be that `image.resize` doesn't return an actual object?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm going to post this as a new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791428/why-is-this-save-method-not-resizing-the-image

Comment: someone told me to move super.save() line to right below image_resized=kwargs.pop,  does this make sense to you?

Comment: i think you need change `if self.photo and image_resized:` to `if self.photo and not image_resized:`. Because in your version it had never execute,