# Why is this save method not resizing the image?

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I am overriding the save method in order to resize the image after upload.  The following code does not appear to be resizing the image, I double checked the media folder and there is only one copy of the uploaded image in it's original dimensions (900x850).  Django is not throwing any errors, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the problem.  To be clear, I am able to submit form and upload image without any problem, but the image is not resizing as I have intended below

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="...", blank=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Did we have to resize the image?
    # We pop it to remove from kwargs when we pass these along
    image_resized = kwargs.pop('image_resized',False)

    if self.photo and image_resized:
        basewidth = 300
        filename = self.get_source_filename()
                image = Image.open(filename)
        wpercent = (basewidth/float(image.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(image.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
        img = image.resize((basewidth,hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.photo = img
        # Save the updated photo, but inform when we do that we
        # have resized so we don't try and do it again.
        self.save(image_resized = True)

    super(Mymodel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the error logs .... most likely, you have not declared the get_source_filename method